# Create Array of Actual Objects C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I want to create an array to store actual objects and not pointers to objects in C++?

Can somebody explain how do I do that? is it better to use vectors or just directly like:

```
Student s [10];
```

OR

```
Student s [10][];
```

Comment: Does the second one even compile?

Comment: no, the second one doesn't compile.  There are very few places in C++ where `[]` is valid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
Student s [10];
```

Creates an array of 10 `Student` instances.

I think that `Student s [10][];` is invalid.

But with C++ I'd not use C type arrays, it's better to use classes like [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) or C++0x [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/array/) which may not be available with not up-to date standard libraries/compilers.

Example for the above with a `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<Student> students(10);
```

And with an `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

...

std::array<Student, 10> students;
```

Comment: thanks man I wanted to accept ur full answer but it doesn't allow me to do so :((

Comment: One more Q:
how can I define Vector size in header file? can't I? How to redefine it then in the cc file?

Comment: A `std::vector` has no fixed size, you can `.push_back()` elements into it (and remove them). You can retrieve the current size with `.size()`.

Comment: thnx but I have a known size of this vector.. Is it better fixing its size in advance?

Comment: If you type the size of the vector in its constructor like in the example above (`std::vector<Student> students(10);`) it has this as its initial size. If you don't remove elements from or insert elements into the `std::vector` the size does not change and you can use your fixed size. But unfortunately you cannot fix the size of the vector to a certain amount, but this should not worry you.

Comment: @shaklasah: if you want a fixed size vector, you want `std::array`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use arrays. Arrays are C not c++. Use `std::vector` instead, which is the C++ way to handle this.

Comment: Can u suggest me a way to use Vectors to store actuall objects? thanks

Comment: @shaklasah: vectors always store actual objects unless you specifically tell them otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using std::vector if you want to make your array growable, otherwise just use Student students[10]; for 10 objects.